# How to create a VPN Connection to Azure VNet to use the VNet's Public IP Address for internet traffic

Tags: azure, networking, vpn

I have a number of developers working remotely that need to access external services that require a static IP address.

We created an Azure Virtual Network with a public IP that we wanted to use for this purpose. We have setup a Virtual Network Gateway and successfully connected clients (on macOS) to it... however, it appears that this setup drops internet traffic on the VPN connection, and the clients IP remains the same when accessing the internet.

A bit more reading seems that this is the case for the P2S setup we have. Is there anyway I can enable 'forced tunneling' of internet traffic through the VPN when it is connected? Or some other components that need added to do so?